# django urlpatterns order

Tags: python, django

I ran into a problem loading the admin section of my django site with the following error:

```
No FlatPage matches the given query.
```

I managed to solve the problem, but I'm attempting to understand *why* it solved the problem. In my urls.py file, I moved the url(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')), *after* the url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), and voila, it worked. Can someone explain, briefly, why this would make a relevant difference? Should the admin url always be at the top of the list?

Code the produced the error:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    url (r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

This is django 1.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have not installed the [flatpages application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/flatpages/) correctly. Django's flatpages application relies on a piece of [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/flatpages/#django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware) that intercepts 404 requests. As a result, you do not need to add `django.contrib.flatpages.urls` to your `urls.py`.

You received that error because the regex you are using (`''`) matches **all** URLs. As a result, the urlpattern never reached `^admin/'`.

Comment: Thanks, Martey. I've been following a book that told me to install it as I did... but it's quite out of date now. Probably best to use the docs.