# Django URL Mapping: How to remove app name from URL paths?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a Django app named 'myapp' and my index page in my url.py in the "myapp" directory as:

```
 url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
```

So this essentially makes the URL in the test server `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/`

However, I don't want this. I want every url to start simply at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` so a page that is currently only accessible at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/bigduck` on the test server, I want to instead make it accessible only at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/bigduck/`

Basically, I want to just remove the app name from the url mapping scheme of this app.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look inside the main `urls.py` file of your project (e.g. the one `settings.ROOT_URLCONF` points to, not the one inside the individual apps)

In that main `urls.py` you will see an entry that maps the urls of your `myapp` to the URL path `myapp/`.

You can replace that with something like this:

```
url(r'^$', 'myapp.urls')
```

Which will put all the urls under `myapp`, on the top level path, so you won't need to use `myapp/`

### Edit

You can also map `bigduck` in your main `urls.py`, e.g.

```
bigduck/ -> myapp.bigduck
register/ -> register
```

but what I meant in my comment is that the order in which the regex of URLs appear in your `urls.py` file is important, because Django will stop at the first match, that's why all your URLs are mapped to the `myapp`

Look at number 3 here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This works just as intended for the example index page. But what about for other pages such as:
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register')
that URL for example is mapped to /myapp/register, but even after changing the  project urls file and removing "myapp" from the url mapping which fixed the index page doesn't fix this map. If I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/register/ then I still get a 404

Comment: Try playing with the order of the entries, like put the `r'^register/$` ones before the super wide `r'^$'` that would swallow everything

Comment: You mean to put them in my url.py file for the "myapp" directory right? Because for some reason, I can't get any of the URLs to work in the myapp.urls file after I change my project folder/main urls file to exclude /myapp/

Comment: Made an edit, you might have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934969/django-urlpatterns-order

Comment: Thanks very much for being responsive. I think the issue is that I don't really know how to map "myapp" pages in the main url.py file of the project. For example, is this the correct syntax for mapping the bigduck page in the main urls.py of the project:

url(r'^bigduck/$', myapp.views.bigduck, name='bigduck')

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2019 / django >= 2.0**

Edit your main `urls.py` - the one in the same directory as your `settings.py` file.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # updated so we don't need the myapp prefix
    # path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')), # old version
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```